# Connect a client to two servers with the same IP and port

Tags: c, sockets

I have a client program that needs to connect to two servers. Both are hosted on the same IP address.

This is how I configure the server socket for both servers:

```
int socketConfig (connection_info cinfo) {

    int socketfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (socketfd < 0) {
        write(1, "Socket error\n", strlen("Socket error\n"));
        return -1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in s_addr;
    memset (&s_addr, 0, sizeof (s_addr));
    s_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s_addr.sin_port = htons(cinfo.port);
    s_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if (bind (socketfd, (void *) &s_addr, sizeof (s_addr)) < 0) {
        write(1, "Bind error\n", strlen("Bind error\n"));
        return -1;
    }

    listen(socketfd, 3);

    return socketfd;
}
```

And I have also created this function in the client to connect to a server:

```
int connect_to_server(Config config) {
    struct sockaddr_in client;
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    
    if (sockfd < 0) return -1;
    
    memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));

    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client.sin_port = htons(config.port);

    if (inet_aton(config.ip, &client.sin_addr) == 0) return -1;

    if (connect(sockfd, (void *) &client, sizeof(client)) < 0) return -1;
   
    return sockfd;
}
```

As you can see, `connect_to_server` function connects to a server with IP and port given in a `struct` named `Config`.

My question is:
Can I configure both servers using the same IP and port? Or I need to, at least, change the port number? If I can use same port in both cases, will `connect_to_server` work to connect to both servers just calling it twice?

Comment: "If I wish to place phone-calls to two different places, can they have the exact same info that I enter, or must there be something that differentiates them?" - my mind was literally turning your question into that as I read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the servers on the same computer, they must be bound to different ports. Otherwise, you won't be able to bind the second server socket if the first has already been bound (port already in use).

Comment: ...and if you manually configure two computers to have the same IP, you will stuff your network:)